# How could I achieve this toolbar in ionic angular?

Tags: java, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

[image: Toolbar image]

I want to make the above toolbar in ionic, I'm very new to ionic and I'm struggling to recreate the image in code. I've tried doing a grid but struggling because of the differing sizes of the three buttons. I've also tried doing them as individual buttons but I get half-way through but then start getting stuck. Any help would be very appreciate

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better have the background as image and place the Account and Settings buttons with

```
.buttons-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   margin?
}
```

and for the green button, I would use to center it:

```
.plus-button{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top?
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, I'm having some problems trying to set a background image I've put some details below if you have any suggestions, I'm probably doing something very obvious wrong

Comment: Hi @Meganmooker if the answer helped you please  mark it and vote :)
For setting backgrond image you can use 
 background-image: url("image.gif");